# how do you make a simple clock in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am wondering if I can make a moving clock without having to refresh. This is my current code:

```
:clks
cls
echo.
echo ======
echo %DATE%
echo %TIME%
echo ======
timeout -t 1 >nul
goto clks
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What output are you expecting?

Comment: I don't want it to keep flashing; it's distracting

Comment: Batch file doesn't work like how you want - go switch another language like `C`

Comment: In Windows 10 you can avoid using `cls` by using virtual terminal sequences to move the cursor to a previous line and delete lines from the screen buffer, e.g. `echo %CSI%4A%CSI%4M%CSI%1A` deletes the previous 4 lines, which can go after the timeout to allow echoing the 'clock' in place. Here `%CSI%` contains `\x1b[`. You need an editor that lets you enter or paste the U+001B escape character into the batch script.

Comment: @eryksun: You can move the cursor in any windows version using the [Move cursor to *any position* using just ECHO command](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7898) trick...

Comment: @Aacini, interesting as a fallback in simple cases, but for older systems I'd prefer to add virtual terminal support using ANSICON, or maybe ConEmu.

Comment: The problem is, that `echo` is inredible slow. If you don't want to use the mentioned methods, using `title %date% %time%` might be an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%i in () do (
cls
echo/
echo ======
echo !DATE!
echo !TIME!
echo ======
timeout -t 1 > nul
)
```

Comment: Hey, that's actually a pretty good idea! But it uses ~20% of my CPU on my i5-6500 :(

Comment: How is this an improvement with respect to the flashing problem? For me the result is indistinguishable from running the OP's code that uses `goto`.

Comment: On my system, the `for` loop is actually less flash than `goto`. I think this depends on the hardware you have.

Comment: Any way to hide milliseconds? I keep mistaking milliseconds for seconds :(

Comment: Which milliseconds? `%time%` variable show seconds with _two decimals_, that is, _centiseconds_. Use: `echo !TIME:~0,-3!`

Answer (score 0):

This is an *near* real time clock, using the ping command to create an delay short enough to visualize the milliseconds.

```
@echo off
@mode con cols=25 lines=3
title Clock
color 0f

:loop
echo        %date% 
echo       %time% 

for /l %%I in (1,1,2) do ping -n 01 127.0.0.1 > nul

cls
goto loop
```

The first block of code is mostly just visual enhancements. The pure clock code is:

```
@echo off
:loop
echo %date% 
echo %time% 
for /l %%I in (1,1,2) do ping -n 01 127.0.0.1 > nul
cls
goto loop
```

Instabilities like flashing can be fixed by increasing the number of pings in the for loop (currently 2), just be aware that doing so will make the clock run less smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

@echo off
:12
title %time%
goto 12